# What exactly is installed with apt-get install?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, owncloud

I am trying to install Owncloud on my VPS and I had issues with the migration from version 8 to version 9. So I decided to `apt-get purge owncloud && apt-get install owncloud` to get a fresh installation.

The bad news is my configuration is still there, somewhere. I have absolutely no idea what is installed with `apt-get install` and, more important, where.

If I have this information I can figure out where is my config and how to reconfigure Apache to point to my new owncloud installation.

**EDIT**

My current issue is that I have absolutely no idea where the wwwroot is installed. I have nothing inside `/var/www` neither in `/usr/share/`. Knowing what was installed using apt-get might be very useful...

Comment: `dpkg -L owncloud`?

Comment: Yes! `dpkg -L owncloud` that was the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`owncloud` is a big package with a lot of different things.

You should have:

- An apache configuration file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` (probably named *owncloud.conf*)
- A table in a database. This is up to how you configured owncloud the first time. The config of your owncloud is in that table.
- The files of owncloud itself. If you `remove`d it probably they are gone.

For the database:

If you have MySQL, do

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

to connecto to the database, then do

```
SHOW DATABASES;
```

check if you have a database that is named similar to owncloud, and then drop it:

```
DROP DATABASE databaseName;
```

In this way your configuration should be gone.

If you have PostgreSQL, the procedure is similar, but with different commands:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
\l
DROP DATABASE databaseName;
```